# Dynamic Routing for Dynamic Components in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

A dynamic component with Dynamic Routing is needed for me in Vue3. I wanted to render the component which is coming from the params (path named id) from the router.ts

As you can see here in router.ts I have a dynamic parameter named as id. I wanted the same component to be rendered with the same name.

For example: If http://localhost:3000/forms/form/FirstPage is entered it should render the FirstPage component which I had already created in my project.

and when http://localhost:3000/forms/form/SecondPage is entered it should render the SecondPage component and so on...

My question is how to do it I have tried multiple ways and one of the ways is like that:

```
  {
    path: "/forms/form/:id",
    component: () => import("../pages/" + location.pathname.slice(1) + ".vue")
  },
```

But it is not working. Below I have also shared my App.vue and router/index.ts code

1. This is my router/index.ts file

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter, useRoute } from "vue-router"
import FirstPage from "../pages/FirstPage.vue"
import SecondPage from "../pages/SecondPage.vue"
import ThirdPage from "../pages/ThirdPage.vue"
import NotFound from "../components/NotFound.vue"
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "first",
    component: FirstPage
  },
  {
    path: "/2/70",
    name: "second",
    component: SecondPage
  },
  {
    path: "/3/70",
    name: "third",
    component: ThirdPage
  },
  {
    path: "/forms/form/:id",
    component: () => import("../pages/" + location.pathname.slice(1) + ".vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
    component: NotFound
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

2. App.vue file

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>router/index.ts file
```

Comment: You shouldn't access location.pathname directly, and certainly not at the point when route component is resolved. Wrap dynamic component with another component and make a decision there, based on useRoute data

Comment: Hi, Can you brief what you mean by wrapping another dynamic component? Can you share 1-2 lines of code related to your idea?

Comment: I added the post. Though it makes more sense to specify routes explicitly, or specify dynamic comps with v-if enumeration, unless you have tons of them

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have a dynamic component around 10-40 in the future, because as the no of pages are going to increase, the route shall need to be linked automatically with it. v-if enumeration is not going to work even for 5-10 pages.

Comment: What exactly does "not able to find the value" mean? Is there an error? Why is it `1` initially? v-if is not really a bad solution in terms of maintenance even with 10+ conditions

Comment: Hi, I am getting these following as error/warning: [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
FormWrapper.vue:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: ref is not defined
    at FormWrapper.vue:10:18
(anonymous) @ FormWrapper.vue:10

Comment: And also can you tell me how shall I link <component :is="PageComp"/>

... this with the FirstPage, SecondPage component.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You didn't import `ref`, it's not defined. Also component code from the answer belongs to setup block. It should be in setup function or in <script setup>, it doesn't make sense at the top of <script>

Comment: I have rectified the mistakes which you have pointed out now. But have a doubt, as right now it is returning all the components mentioned in the template. What 1-2 line if condition shall I need to make sure that it renders only the component which is PageComp.value. Link : https://github.com/semanux/interaction-collection/blob/poc/dynamic-paging-dynamic-component/src/pages/FormWrapper.vue

Comment: Consider addressing the code I posted. It mentions <component :is="PageComp"/> , no FirstPage, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.pathname` isn't generally supposed to be accessed directly in Vue router. It shouldn't be accessed at the point when route component is resolved because the location isn't changed yet.

Dynamic component can be wrapped with another component:

```
  {
    path: "/semanux/form/:id",
    component: FormWrapperPage,
  },
```

Where wrapper component is something like:

```
<component :is="PageComp"/>

...

const route = useRoute();
const PageComp = ref();

watch(
  () => route.params.id,
  async id => {
    try {
      PageComp.value = (await import("../pages/" + id + ".vue")).default
    } catch {
       router.push('/404')
    }
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
```

Since dynamic component is rendered after navigation, missing components need to be handled manually.